# How to group two sublists together such that both sublist doesn't contain any similar item

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group

I want to group two sublists together such that both sublists doesn't have any common element..

eg:

```
lst=[[10],[10,30],[30],[30,50],[50]
Res=[10,30] : [50] and [10] : [30,50]
```

Comment: There is multiple solutions to this. Why do you chose `[[10,30], [50]]` and `[[10], [30,50]]` rather than `[[10], [30], [50]]`, `[[10,30]]` and `[[30,50]]`? Is it always possible to generate exactly two sublists without common elements? That's a significant constraint on the input data...

Comment: I have to pick one element of len 1 and another of len 2..in case of 5 element I have to chose 1 element of len 3 and other of len 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution. The desired lengths of sublists need to be defined explicitly (`target_lengths`).

```
lst=[[10],[10,30],[30],[30,50],[50]]
target_lengths = [1, 2]

# get relevant sublists and cast to sets
sets = [set(sublist) for sublist in lst if len(sublist) in target_lengths]

def agg_unique(collect_sets, remain_sets):
    if not remain_sets:
        # if remain_sets is empty, return results (with sets converted to lists)
        return [list(map(list, sublist)) for sublist in collect_sets]
    
    new_sets = []  # new list of sets meeting all criteria, e.g. [{10}, {30, 50}]
    new_total_set = set()  # flattened set, e.g. {10, 30, 50}
    allowed_lengths = target_lengths[:]  # copy allowed lengths list

    for set_ in remain_sets:
        set_len = len(set_)
        # only append to results if none of the elements of set_ is in new_total_set 
        # and we are still allowed a set of the length
        if not (new_total_set & set_) and set_len in allowed_lengths:
            new_sets.append(set_)
            new_total_set.update(set_)
            allowed_lengths.remove(set_len)

    new_remain_sets = [c for c in remain_sets if not c in new_sets]
    # only append if new_sets matches target_lengths, e.g. *not* [{30}]
    new_collect_sets = collect_sets + ([new_sets] 
                                       if sorted(target_lengths) 
                                           == sorted(list(map(len, new_sets))) 
                                       else [])
    # return recursive function call
    return agg_unique(new_collect_sets, new_remain_sets)
    
agg_unique([], sets)
```

Resulting in output:

```
# [[[10], [50, 30]], [[10, 30], [50]]]
```